# Big-O; order of growth rates

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Order the growth rates of the following functions: 
    10<sup>−5</sup>n, 10<sup>2</sup>log n, 3<sup>n</sup>, n log n, 10<sup>−100</sup>n<sup>2</sup> + 10<sup>3</sup>n, n<sup>n</sup>

Then prove each of the relations. For example: if the ordering is A < B < C < D, then prove A = O(B), B = O(C) and C = O(D). You should prove either based on the definition of big-O, or based on the limit of ratios (with L’Hˆopital’s rule if necessary). Do not use any conclusions on function growth rates.

---

Based on the math that I have done, I have come to the conclusion that the correct order is as follows:

10<sup>2</sup>log n < 10<sup>−5</sup>n < n log n < 10<sup>−100</sup>n<sup>2</sup> + 10<sup>3</sup>n < 3<sup>n</sup> < n<sup>n</sup>

I am having trouble proving this however. I have calculated that log n has a smaller growth rate than n which has a smaller growth rate than n log n. And I know that in terms of growth rate, n2 is less than 3<sup>n</sup> which is less than n<sup>n</sup>. How should I approach proving these relations?

Comment: This is better suited for https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt I feel that big-o and growth rate is programming specific. Those tags don't even exist in math.stackexchange. My initial thought was to post there. Then found all related questions on this site, so I posted here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great spot to work with the fact that f(n) = O(g(n)) if and only if

> lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> f(n) / g(n) = L

for some value of L. For example, let's look at 3<sup>n</sup> versus n<sup>n</sup>. Taking the limit of the ratio gives

> lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> 3<sup>n</sup> / n<sup>n</sup>
>
> = lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> (3 / n)<sup>n</sup>
>
> = 0

So 3<sup>n</sup> = o(n<sup>n</sup>). You should be able to use a similar technique to reason about all of the other quantities here. The trickiest one will be comparing the log term to the other ones; for that, as suggested, use l'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 0):

> if the ordering is A < B < C < D, then prove A = O(B), B = O(C) and C = O(D).

So this is just a chain of proofs. For your ordering, which is indeed correct, we have:

[image: ordering]

First, we'll prove that A = O(B), so in this case

[image: bigo1]

By the definition of the Big-Oh notation, given by @templatetypef, we compute that indeed 
 [image: bigo1] by looking at the limit of the ratios

[image: calculations]

The rest is analogous, now go prove that *10^(-5)n = O(n log n)*. At the end, you'll have prooved the complete ordering relation.

Comment: I guess where my confusion stems form is how that ends up equaling out to 0?

Comment: As n goes to infinity, 1/n is 1 over something infinetly big, and this goes to 0(Think of it as 1/10, then 1/1000, then 1/9999999999999, it all gets smaller and converges to zero for n infinetly big). You should be allowed to use this basic limit. (lim n->infty 1/n = 0).

Comment: So would I be correct in the following: 10^(-5)n / nlogn = 10^(-5) / logn = 0

Comment: Yes, since log *n* already goes to infinity for *n -> infty*, we have again the situation 1 divided by something infinetly big.

Comment: It might be deceptive to use notation such as `O(10^(-5)n)` to the OP (that is a student of asymptotic notation?), even is this is included in his question. While formally correct, `10^(-5)` is just a constant here, so a possible an initial note the the OP would be to explain that `O(const*g(n))` is just `O(g(n))` (possibly using the formal definition of Bog-O notation).